# Asana API retrieve project owner, status and deadline

Tags: asana, asana-api

Is there a way using the Asana api to retrieve the project owner, project status, project description and project deadline?

I checked the API docs and could not find anything, so I am assuming the answer is no (but confirmation is much appreciated).

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects#sections

If there is not a way of doing this via the API, does anyone have any hacks on how to do this using something like Selenium or another tool?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project overview attributes are accessible attributes on [project objects in the API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects).

- `current_status` is the latest status update for the project including the color and text associated.
- `owner` the current project owner.
- `due_date` the current project due date.

Comment: Thanks so much! Making these items accessible via the API would really increase the amount of people at my company who paying for licenses.